# Server side event connection issue

Tags: html, spring-mvc

In the server side event, eventsource connects to a server over  HTTP connection and receives events in text/event-stream format without closing the connection as per MDN documentation.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource

I have the following code -

```js
/**
 * 
 */

(function(){
 "use strict"
 var init = function(){
  if (window.EventSource) {
      console.log("Event source available");
      var source = new EventSource('/message');

      source.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
          var container = document.getElementById("container");
          container.innerHTML += e.data;
      });

      source.addEventListener('open', function(e) {
           console.log("Connection was opened.");
      }, false);

      source.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
           if (e.readyState == EventSource.CLOSED) {
               console.log("Connection was closed.");
           } else {
               console.log(e.readyState);    
           }
      }, false);
   } else {
           console.log("No SSE available");
   }
 }
 init();
 
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Index file</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ssescript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 This is the index file.
 <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and at server side I am using Spring MVC

```
  package com.example.controller;

import java.util.Random;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


@RestController
public class AppController {


    @RequestMapping("/message")
    public String getMessage(HttpServletResponse response){
        response.setContentType("text/event-stream");
        Random r = new Random();
         return "data:Testing 1,2,3 "+r.nextInt()+"\n\n";
    }

}
```

Each time the browser opens a new connection and close it. Can we open the EventSource connection only once and keep pushing the data from the server ??

Comment: Seems to need support from browser;)

Comment: I tried it with Google Chrome 50.0.2661.102

Comment: What about adding `@ResponseBody ` to your controller method?

Comment: Tried this as well, still opening new connection :(

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same error.

After a lot of trial and error, I found that it was Tomcat closing the connection because of a default setting in Spring. I set the Async request timeout to a number large enough to accomodate my needs.

spring.mvc.async.request-timeout=(some really big number)